# how to using unique id getElementsByClassName for creating id ul and li tag each word from textarea

Tags: javascript, html

Words For each space make `ul` have a new class
Then put the word inside `li` By clicking on the button

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>

</head>

<body>

  <textarea id ="myArea"class="rebaz"rows=4 cols=50>hello my name is rebaz</textarea>
 <button onclick="show();">Show content</button>
 
 <script>

let contextMenu = document.getElementsByClassName("word id")[0];
 </script>
</body>
<script src="./main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="cheack.js"></script>
</html>
```

after click button Crete dynamically this ul and li

```
<ul class="word1">
    <li>hello</li>
   </ul>
    <ul class="word2">
    <li>my</li>
   </ul>
    <ul class="word3">
    <li>name</li>
   </ul>
    <ul class="word4">
    <li>is</li>
   </ul>
    <ul class="word5">
    <li>rebaz</li>
   </ul>
```

Comment: Why do you want a separate list for each word? Wouldn't it be better to have a list, and one list _item_ for each word?

Comment: I have a project that wants it to be the way I asked.

Comment: @rebazxoshnaw Do you want to extend the ul-li tags structure when the user clicks `show content` button second time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Word Splitter</title>
</head>
<body>
    <textarea id="myArea" class="rebaz" rows="4" cols="50">Hello! my name is Anshu</textarea>
    <button onclick="show();">Show content</button>

    <script>
        function show() {
          // remove existing ul elements if any
          let uls = document.getElementsByTagName('ul');
            while (uls.length > 0) {
                uls[0].parentNode.removeChild(uls[0]);
            }

            let text = document.getElementById('myArea').value;
            let words = text.split(' ');
            for (let i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
                let ul = document.createElement('ul');
                ul.className = 'word' + (i + 1);
                let li = document.createElement('li');
                li.textContent = words[i];
                ul.appendChild(li);
                document.body.appendChild(ul);
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some modern JS principles and methods that can help you out. Here I'm using [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to iterate over the word array and return a new "list" string for each word, [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to build the element strings, and [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) to attach the completed lists string to the DOM.

```js
// Cache the elements
const textarea = document.querySelector('textarea');
const button = document.querySelector('button');

// Add a listener to the button
button.addEventListener('click', handleClick);

function handleClick() {

  // Get, trim, and split the words in the text area
  const wordArr = textarea.textContent.trim().split(' ');

  // Using `map` for each word create a new list HTML string
  // returning a new list element (with class) for each word
  // and then joining the resulting array of template strings
  // into a whole string
  const lists = wordArr.map((word, i) => {
    return `<ul class="word${i + 1}"><li>${word}</li></ul>`;
  }).join('');

  // Finally wrap the items HTML in a parent element, and add it
  // to an appropriate DOM element
  document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<section>${lists}</section>`);
}
```

```css
.word1 { color: red; }
.word2 { color: green; }
.word3 { color: blue; }
.word4 { color: orange; }
.word5 { color: black; }
```

```html
<textarea id ="myArea" rows=4 cols=50>hello my name is rebaz</textarea>
<button type="button">Show content</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>

</head>

<body>

  <textarea id ="myArea"class="rebaz"rows=4 cols=50>hello my name is rebaz</textarea>
 <button onclick="show();">Show content</button>
 
 <script>
    function show(){
      let textArea = document.querySelector("#myArea");
      let body = document.querySelector("body")
      let words = textArea.value.split(" ");
      // now loop through all words and create ul for each word
      let count = 1;
      words.forEach((word)=>{
        let ul = document.createElement("ul");
        ul.setAttribute("id",`word${count}`)
        ul.innerHTML = `<li> ${word} </li>`
        //add element ul to body
        body.appendChild(ul)
        //increase count
        count++;
        
      })
    }
 </script>
</body>
<script src="./main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="cheack.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <textarea id ="myArea"class="rebaz"rows=4 cols=50>hello my name is rebaz</textarea>
    <button onclick="show();">Show content</button>
    <ul id="showText"></ul>
 
 
 <script defer>
 function show(){
   let selectUL = document.getElementById('showText');
   let AllText=document.getElementById("myArea").value;

   const text = AllText.split(" ")
   
   selectUL.innerHTML=""
   text.map((item)=>{
       var li = document.createElement('li');
             li.innerText = item;
             selectUL.appendChild(li);
     });
   }
 </script>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Add the logic to clear ul and li tags when user try to look for different content. You can refer mine. Btw, Your solution looks pretty clean

Comment: This code generates `LI` elements as direct children of the `DIV.showText` element and **not** as children of a `UL` element

Comment: @MotalibHossain When you click 'show content'` for second time, it should show the display current text as ul and li tags. But, in your case, it just extends it and append the current to previous content. @professor-abronsius comment is correct, read it please.

Comment: @Anshu please kindly check the updated answer I provided. Thank you.

Comment: @MotalibHossain If you're not returning a value from the `map` callback you should use `forEach` instead.