# How to move words from the textAraea to each in the 'ol' element, JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

The first word in the textarea should enter class "word1" with append tag 'li', then the second word should enter class "word2" with tag 'li' and the other words in the same order
if no more word from textarea class ol should be emtty

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>

  
</head>

<textarea class="rebaz"rows=4 cols=50>hello my name is rebaz</textarea>
<button onclick="show();">Show content</button>
<ol class = "word1"></ol>
<ol class = "word2"></ol>
<ol class = "word3"></ol>
<ol class = "word4"></ol>
<ol class = "word5"></ol>
<ol class = "word6"></ol>
   

 
</body>


</html>
```

**after click button**

```
<ol class = "word1"><li>hello</li></ol>
<ol class = "word2"><li>my</li></ol>
<ol class = "word3"><li>name</li></ol>
<ol class = "word4"><li>is</li></ol>
<ol class = "word5"><li>rebaz</li></ol>
<ol class = "word6"></ol>
```

Comment: this is just a modified version of a [question you posed yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77634232) where answers were given that basically answer this

Comment: Whats the reason for having a new `ol` for each word? Semantically this makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have a JavaScript function that will split words from the [textarea](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea) value and will create a new [`li`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li) element for each one of them to be appended to the corresponding [`ol`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ol) element selected by its class.

I should point out that if the textarea contains more than six words, the seventh and counting will be ignored. That's by design according to your requirements. I should also warn that doing lists with single items is pretty meaningless. Just as a reminder, *ol* stands for ordered list and *li* stands for list item.

I added at the beginning of the function, the code to empty all the `ol` elements (having a class beginning with `word`) before proceeding so that at each execution (press of the button) it will refresh the status.

Eventually I also better styled the lists so that the counter will be unique among all the `ol[class^="word"]`.

```js
function show(){
  document.querySelectorAll('ol[class^=word]')
    .forEach(ol => ol.innerHTML = '');
  const source = document.getElementById('textarea');
  const words = source.value.split(' ');
  words.forEach((word, i) => {
    const li = document.createElement('li');
    li.textContent = word;
    document.querySelector(`.word${i+1}`)?.append(li);
  });
}
```

```css
body {
  counter-reset: listCounter; /*defines one counter only*/
}

ol[class^="word"] {
  list-style-type: none; /*hides the default numbering*/
  padding: 0;
}

ol[class^="word"] > li {
  counter-increment: listCounter; /*increment the counter at each li*/
  border: solid 1px gray;
  padding: .5em 1em;
}

ol[class^="word"] > li::before {
  content: counter(listCounter) ". "; /*show the counter at each li*/
  font-weight: 600;
}

button{
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="textarea" class="rebaz" rows=4 cols=50>hello my name is rebaz</textarea>
<br>
<button onclick="show();">Show content</button>
<ol class = "word1"></ol>
<ol class = "word2"></ol>
<ol class = "word3"></ol>
<ol class = "word4"></ol>
<ol class = "word5"></ol>
<ol class = "word6"></ol>
```

Comment: i went different class ol no li

Comment: I read the edited question being much different than its former version... now the `ol` elements are expected to exist already, and they are filled with the corresponding word (as a single `li` element). If there are more than 6 words in the input, they will be ignored. I should warn you that doing lists like that is pretty meaningless

Comment: Finally I found what I was looking for. Thank you very much

Comment: sorry how to rest after second click button no display first click. result

Comment: added  the part at the beginning that refreshes the status so that you can repeat the operation arbitrary times

Answer (score 0):

You can do `insertAdjacentHTML`

```js
function show() {
  const textarea = document.querySelector('textarea.rebaz');
  const value = textarea.value;
  const split = value && value.split(' ');
  if (split && split.length) {
    split.forEach((item, index) => {
      textarea.insertAdjacentHTML("afterEnd", `<ol class = "word${index}">${item}</ol>`);
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<textarea class="rebaz" rows=4 cols=50>hello my name is rebaz</textarea>
<button onclick="show();">Show content</button>
```

Comment: ol should be have in html source code don't create by JavaScript element

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript's trim, split, getElementsByClassName, and appendChild methods to solve this. The `trim` method is useful for removing the extra whitespace in the textarea.

In the show method, you can first grab the textarea tag by-

```
const textarea = document.getElementsByClassName("rebaz")[0];
```

There getElementsByClassName gives an array type data structure. So, you need to write `[0]` to get the first element. After grabbing the textarea you can trim the text inside it and split it based on space (' ').

```
const words = textarea.value.trim().split(" ");
```

It will return an array containing words. These words can be inserted into the *ol* tag.

The show function can be written as-

```
function show() {
    // Grabbing the textarea
    const textarea = document.getElementsByClassName("rebaz")[0];
    // Trim the text before the split
    const words = textarea.value.trim().split(" ");

    words.forEach((word, idx) => {
      // Getting the ol tag
      const ol = document.getElementsByClassName(`word${idx + 1}`);
      // Check if the ol tag exists in the html
      if (ol.length > 0) {
        // Creating a empty li tag
        const li = document.createElement("li");
        // Setting the word inside the li tag
        li.innerText = word;
        // Appending the li tag into the 'ol' container
        ol[0].appendChild(li);
      }
    });
  }
```

You can use a single *ol* tag and multiple *li* tags inside it. The *li* tag will represent each of the words. I think it will make more sense instead of using multiple *ol* tags.

The HTML can be written as-

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Used id -->
    <textarea class="rebaz" id="rebaz" rows="4" cols="50">
      hello my name is rebaz
    </textarea>
    <button onclick="show();">Show content</button>
    <ol id="ol-container"></ol>

    <script>
      function show() {
        // Grabbing the textarea
        const textarea = document.getElementById("rebaz");
        // Trim the text before the split
        const words = textarea.value.trim().split(" ");

        // Grabbing the ol container where the li tags will be appended
        const olContainer = document.getElementById("ol-container");

        words.forEach((word, idx) => {
          // Creating an empty li tag
          const li = document.createElement("li");
          // Giving a class name to the li tag
          li.classList.add(`word${idx + 1}`);
          // Setting the word inside the li tag
          li.innerText = word;
          // Appending the li tag into the ol container
          olContainer.appendChild(li);
        });
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this logic solve your problem. Please try it:

```js
function show() {
    var textareaContent = document.querySelector('.rebaz').value;
    var words = textareaContent.split(' ');

    for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        var olClass = "word" + (i + 1);
        var li = document.createElement('li');
        li.textContent = words[i];

        document.querySelector('.' + olClass).appendChild(li);
    }
}
```

```css
li{list-style: none;}
    ol{background-color: antiquewhite;padding: 10px;}
```

```html
<textarea class="rebaz" rows="4" cols="50">hello my name is rebaz</textarea>
  <button onclick="show()">Show content</button>
  <ol class="word1"></ol>
  <ol class="word2"></ol>
  <ol class="word3"></ol>
  <ol class="word4"></ol>
  <ol class="word5"></ol>
  <ol class="word6"></ol>
```

Comment: how to rest after second click button no display first click